# Recycling a webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm hoping someone can help me understand a process of recycling a webservice using the following method:

At the company where I work, the process is to simply open up the web.config file in an editor, make any kind of modification, and then save the file. The modification can be as simple as entering a space after the last xml node and then removing it.

I'm curious, but how does this end up "recycling the webservice"?

Comment: there's a definite smell to the practice you describe, and it's not a good one...

Comment: @Brian: would you be able to elaborate just a bit?

Comment: there is a way to explicitly recycle any app that's hosted in IIS by recycling its application pool.

Comment: Why do you need to recycle at the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the recommended approach though because if you make an oopsie then your webservice won't come back up.  Its better to go to the IIS application pool manager and recycle it from there.

Comment: You can also use iisreset from the command line but that will reset all of your sites on that machine.  There's probably a command line that you can run to do it for one site.

Comment: that's the information I was looking for, i.e. why it isn't a good idea and what the alternative is. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET has a file system watcher on the config file. From there it boots the application from the app pool/app domain.

A better practice would to set up different app pools and recycle them from IIS.

Answer (score 3):

Updating the web.config actually recycles the application pool for the web services/sites. It also clears out the application cache and session variables if used InProc.